# Group cell values to range based on another cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I need these values to be in this format:

[image]

Comment: Could you explain how you'd get the bottom set of values from the top? I don't see any values that match `001-009`, for example.

Comment: There is a lot of values which fit to 001-009, i only copied here the beginning.

Comment: 00100=001, its a new format.

Comment: So we'd expect the whole of the first table to be included in `001-009` - in which case, shouldn't that row show a total of more than 1?

Comment: Please, clarify the conversion you're doing, it's not clear from the data. Original data is 5 digit numbers and result is 6 digits.

Comment: This could easily be the worst question of the day (no offence). Two pictures and a line of text telling us you need something.... Have a look at [ask] a question with a [mcve]. Include sample data in markdown format, what you have tried yourself, what didn't work and expected result. Right now it's actually a question to ask us to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRowA As Long, i As Long, StartPoint As Long, EndPoint As Long, y As Long, LastRowD As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim Char1 As String, Char2 As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Find the last row of Column A
        LastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Set the range with data
        arr = .Range("A1:A" & LastRowA)

        StartPoint = 1

            'Loop the range with data
            For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

                If StartPoint <= i Then

                    Char1 = Mid(arr(i, 1), 3, 1)

                    'Loop to find match
                    For y = i + 1 To UBound(arr)

                        Char2 = Mid(arr(y, 1), 3, 1)

                        If Char1 <> Char2 Then
                            EndPoint = y - 1
                            Exit For
                       End If

                    Next y

                    LastRowD = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

                    .Range("D" & LastRowD + 1).Value = Right(.Range("A" & StartPoint).Value, (Len(.Range("A" & StartPoint).Value) - 1)) & " - " & Right(.Range("A" & EndPoint).Value, (Len(.Range("A" & EndPoint).Value) - 1))

                    StartPoint = y

                End If

            Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Results:

[image]